# Role management in MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, roles, asp.net-identity-2

I am looking for role and permission management in MVC6. Basically my requirement is I will be having roles and those roles will have some set of permissions(Like Add,Edit,Delete,Modify etc.).

So, based on this I want to achieve following things

1. Show/Hide content of view based on role and there permission for user.
2. To restrict access to controller and its action methods.

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: Is there a specific problem you hit while implementing your solution?

Comment: ASP.Net Identity 3.0 is part of core. Have you looked at that?

Comment: @trailmax How can I get the roles and there permissions for user on run time instead of decorating them on top of action methods. Is it fine if I check the permissions in controller level for hiding portion of view ? If yes how can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer:

## 2: Just add attributes to your controller and/or methods, e.g.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, PowerUser")]
public class ControlPanelController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SetTime()
    {
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public ActionResult ShutDown()
    {
    }
}
```

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/roles.html